# Modify canvas size in gnuplot

Tags: canvas, size, gnuplot, sample, graphic

I have 300 samples represented, at the moment of representing this data in a graph, it is not possible to distinguish the separation between each sample, How can I do so that the samples are separated a little more and look clearer.

Current output:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "distinguish the separation between each sample"? You could try `plot .... with impulses`

Comment: I am trying to draw really a lot of data, so lines start to overlap each other (x-positions are so close to each other that lines cannot be visualised without drawing one over another).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, there are a few things you could try. First, make your point smaller using:

```
plot "<jot -r 300" with linespoints ps 0.5
```

[image: linespoints]

You can also use impulses instead:

```
plot "<jot -r 300" with impulses
```

[image: impulses]

Or, assuming you know what your range of `x` values is, split it in two of more panels:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set xrange [0:150]
plot "<jot -r 300" not w imp
set xrange [150:300]
plot "<jot -r 300" not w imp
```

[image: multiplot]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. The point size and using impulses really help to see te values. :)